# How can i convert py file to an apk file?

Tags: python, apk, opencv

Please answer this fast. I want to convert an .py file to .apk file so i can run it on Android. It is just one simple program that uses cv2 module to detect faces and make alerts with no ui (user interface) and gui/window.I don't have a problem with code, but i have problem with converting.

I tried with Buildozer, but i have some errors with downloading. It says that buildozer-remote.exe and buildozer.exe files are not in system PATH, so it doesnt work. I opened environment variables and made new one with that path, but it is the same as on start. Also, i am using Windows so it doesn't work. Kivy dont fit to me. Recommend me other program?

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/5763413)

Comment: Buildozer supports only Linux systems not windows as a result you will get the error.
You can try moving your code in the Ubuntu by creating any Virtual Machine and then proceed with further steps if you don't have any Linux based system

Answer (score 1):

You can use google colab to convert your python kivy project to an apk.